# Would domain forwarding or parking get my visitors to the same page?

Tags: domains, redirects, 301-redirect, domain-forwarding

I own the domains `example.com` and `example.org` from two different registrars.

The main site is hosted under `example.org`. What is the better method for getting visitors to each domain to land on the same pages?

1. In the domain control panel of `example.com` I set to redirect domain to `example.org`, with 301 permanent setting.
2. In the hosting control panel of `example.org` I add example.com as a parked domain (and change example.com DNS accordingly).

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each method?

Answer (score 2):

Using 301 permanent redirects from one domain to the other is your better option.

In fact, "domain parking" won't achieve what you want at all.   Parking a domain generally means that the registrar will put up its own page there.  That page will generally say "coming soon" and have advertisements for the registrar's services.